# Sql Developer - Can you use a case statement in a cursor to return multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, case

I've been working through a task of trying to classify several million rows of data into a variety of different topics. The data involves calls from our customer support, and we're trying to find a way to classify each call into one of 109 topics. Due to the confidentiality of the data I can't disclose any of the actual data, but will try to give a relatable subset of data that other people could compare to.

### DATA:

Incident_Number |   Call_Description
000123456    | Issue with oranges and apples 

000987654    | oranges

004567891    | with apples and kiwis

026589741    | Issue with kiwis

### SQL:

select
Incident_Number,
Call_Description,
(case
when call_description like '%oranges%' then oranges
when call_description like '%apples%' then apples
when call_descritpion like '%kiwis%' then 'kiwis'
else 'Unclassified' end) Topic
from DATA

### Question

My hope would be to have Incident 000123456 classified as both oranges and apples and Incident 004567891 get classified as apples and kiwis

### Desired Output

Incident_Number |   Call_Description ......................| Topic
000123456   ........ | Issue with oranges and apples | oranges
000123456   ........ | Issue with oranges and apples | apples 

000987654 ........   | oranges ...................................| oranges

004567891    .........| with apples and kiwis............... | apples

004567891    .........| with apples and kiwis............... | kiwis

026589741    .........| Issue with kiwis........................ | kiwis

### Wrapup

From my limited knowledge and what I've garnered from research a simple case statement can't do this because it short circuits after finding the first true value. My question is whether or not it is possible to make some alterations to my code OR instead to somehow set up a cursor to run through my initial table and give me the desired output noted above.

I appreciate any help or advice and hope that I've adhered to the rules of this website (which has honestly saved my butt before!)

Regards,
Richard

Comment: Is this a typo? "when call_descritpion like '%kiwis%' then '%kiwis%'"

Comment: Yep sorry totally a typo there!

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft SQL Server instead of Oracle, so I'm not sure about the Oracle syntax, but one solution I have used in the past is to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  groupName  varchar(50)
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
Insert Into my_temp_table (groupName) VALUES('oranges')
Insert Into my_temp_table (groupName) VALUES('apples')
Insert Into my_temp_table (groupName) VALUES('kiwis')
```

then I would inner join to the table to duplicate the records:

```
select
    Incident_Number,
    Call_Description,
    my_temp_table.groupName Topic
from DATA
inner join my_temp_table
    on Data.call_description like '%' + my_temp_table.groupName + '%'
```

One problem with this method is that if a record doesn't fall into any categories, it will be excluded completely.

Comment: The Oracle string concatenation operator is `||` not `+`.

Comment: This method may work really well actually. The problem noted at the bottom wouldn't be much of an issue as I could just join the resulting table back to my initial table and assign those records an 'unclassified' value. I'll need to see how I could alter the code you provided to suit my needs, as my actual queries (from the when statement) is quite a bit more complicated then what I noted, I just tried to simplify for other people who may have the same question. <br>To clarify, would the values in the temp table would be the 109 topics I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that's quite a lot of topics though.

Comment: Looking at your solution more I'm worried that it may not actually be flexible enough for my requirements. To give you an example one of my case whens looks like this - when (description like '%xxx%' or description like '%xxx%') and (description like '%xxx%' or description like '%xxx%') and description like '%cxxx%' and description not like '%xxx%'  then 'unable to xxx or xxxxxxx xxxx'

Comment: Agreed, it is a lot of topics, but sadly they're necessary for me to include. When you're talking about tech support calls for a product that ships internationally, we require the level of granularity for our customer support reps so we can action on issues before they balloon out of control. Makes it very fun data to work with, but my god is it messy!

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to integrate such complex logic. Maybe someone else will though

Comment: fair enough, I really appreciate the help :) If I could upvote I would, but don't have a high enough rep as of this point. I'm going to keep your code for reference later down the road if I can apply it somewhere! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

My exaple is for MS SQL Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e904/2

You could create a table with details and a simple cross join with it

```
create table data(
Incident_Number varchar(9),
Call_Description varchar(50))

create table detail(detail varchar(20))

insert into data select

'000123456','Issue with oranges and apples'
union select
'000987654', 'oranges '
union select
'004567891', 'with apples and kiwis'
union select
'026589741', 'Issue with kiwis'

insert into detail select 'kiwis'
union select 'oranges'
union select 'apples'

select * from data a
 cross join detail b
where a.call_description like '%'||b.detail||'%'
order by a.Incident_Number
```

Add a new version http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3378/1

It manages all incidents identifying those without coincidences with null

```
select * from data a
 left join detail b
on a.call_description like '%'||b.detail||'%'
```

Comment: This is Oracle so the string concatenation operator is `||` not `+`.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks, I'm from MS SQL Server. SQL Fiddle is on SQL Server

Comment: Hey Horaciux. Regarding your response, would it necessitate me doing a union select for each distinct row as you had done above?

Comment: @rhenkel not necesary, it was my way to populate example tables. I just edited my answer adding one more exaple to manage rows with no coincidences in detail

Comment: Alright awesome, thanks for that! (and pardon my noobishness). In a response to Ninsly I had given an example of one of the case statements I'm having to use for classifying the data (ie. case when (call_description like '%xxx%' or call_description like '%xxx%') and (call_description like '%xxx%' or call_description like '%xxx%') and call_description like '%xxx%' and call_description not like '%xxx%' then 'unable to xxx or xxxxxxx xxxx' I'm just concerned that if I just use a details table as opposed to the granularity provided by that case statement I may be missing a lot of the rows

Comment: is it possible to account for that type of logic do you think? Or would I maybe need to use a different method entirely?

Comment: @rhenkel not sure if I follow your new requirement, but it seems to be easily acomplished adding columns to `detail` table, i.e., columns named `OR_Detail` and `AND_Detail`. I think you shuld ask a new question. If you do, let me know by commenting here addressing my name.

Comment: @Horaciux, I'll see if I can better explain the requirement. The call agent writes a summary of an issue the customer reported and it's those summaries which i'm trying to classify. I'll make a fake one for a car company "customer complained that the radio wouldn't turn on and the power windows don't operate." For my purpose I would want to classify the summary as both 'radio' and 'power window issue' using something like (case when call_description like '%radio%' and '%turn on' then radio <br>when call_description like '%power%' and '%windows% then 'power window issue' else unclassified end)

Comment: @Horaciux The problem here is that the call_description would only get classified as 'radio' which makes sense since a case statement short circuits after the first true condition. I'm wondering if it's possible for it to classify it as both, especially when the case statement gets much more complex. I appreciate all your help so far! If you think it would be better for me just to make another question I'll do so, I just wanted to try to rework my question first. Thanks

Comment: @Horaciux sorry wasn't trying to abuse you or anything :( They should add the ability to send donations to people for being downright awesome! I'll try your method and let you know how it goes (and try not to ask any more questions:)) Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: @rhenkel look at this, is in SQL Server, but you will get the idea: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4eb2/1

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create (physically or virtually) a table of keywords and use that to join to your table of data.  Something like

```
WITH keywords AS (
  SELECT 'apples' topic FROM dual UNION 
  SELECT 'oranges' FROM dual UNION 
  SELECT 'kiwis' FROM dual
)
SELECT data.incident_number,
       data.incident_description,
       keywords.topic
  FROM data
       JOIN keywords
         ON( data.incident_description LIKE '%' || keywords.topic || '%' )
```

This will work but it's not the most efficient or flexible approach in the world.  It doesn't handle different forms of the word well (if a description references the singular "apple" for example).  It doesn't handle words that appear within other words (if a description talks about "crabapples" for example).  And it's doing a relatively slow match based on scanning through the entire `incident_description`.

An alternative approach would be to use [Oracle Text](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/index-098492.html) to index your data.  That's likely to be a more complex solution but it would be much more flexible and should be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Justin, sadly based on what you mentioned regarding it not handling different forms of the word well, the solution you posted may not work be the best option for me. To be frank the data I'm handling is incredibly...messy...with lots of variation in the way words have been typed. I'm going to look at Oracle Text as you mentioned and will see if that is a better fit :)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone for the CURSOR option to loop through the records in the table and update each row with the category information.

Because you mentioned your rules are quite complicated I think each one might need to be hand written in this procedure and not stored in a table.

Sorry this is MSSQL so might need converting a little for Oracle.

```
/*BEGIN SETUP TEMP DATA*/
CREATE TABLE #tmp1 (
    idno int,
    title nvarchar(100),    
    Categories nvarchar(100) --I have added this row to my temp data, you could store this in another table if needed.
)

INSERT INTO #tmp1 (idno, title) VALUES (1, 'problem apples and oranges')
INSERT INTO #tmp1 (idno, title) VALUES (2, 'problem with apples')
INSERT INTO #tmp1 (idno, title) VALUES (3, 'problem with oranges')
INSERT INTO #tmp1 (idno, title) VALUES (4, 'problem with kiwis')
INSERT INTO #tmp1 (idno, title) VALUES (5, 'problem with something')
/*END SETUP TEMP DATA*/

/*SETUP VARIABLES TO USE IN CURSOR*/
DECLARE @idno int,
        @title nvarchar(100)

/*DECLARE CURSOR, OPEND IT AND FETCH DATA INTO INTO IT*/
DECLARE incident_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT idno, title
    FROM #tmp1 --You could add WHERE Categories IS NULL to only update records that have not been processed
OPEN incident_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM incident_cursor 
INTO @idno, @title

/*LOOP THROUGH CURSOR*/
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @allCategories nvarchar(100)

    SET @allCategories = ''

    /*WRITE RULES HERE TO WORK OUT WHETHER CATEGORY NEEDS ADDING*/
    IF (@title LIKE '%apples%') BEGIN SET @allCategories = @allCategories + 'Apples ' END
    IF (@title LIKE '%oranges%') BEGIN SET @allCategories = @allCategories + 'Oranges ' END
    IF (@title LIKE '%kiwis%') BEGIN SET @allCategories = @allCategories + 'Kiwis ' END

    IF @allCategories = '' BEGIN SET @allCategories = 'Uncategorised' END

    /*UPDATE ORIGINAL TABLE WITH CATEGORY INFORMATION*/
    UPDATE #tmp1 SET Categories = @allCategories WHERE idno = @idno

FETCH NEXT FROM incident_cursor 
    INTO @idno, @title
END 
CLOSE incident_cursor;
DEALLOCATE incident_cursor;

/*THIS ARE JUST TO DISPLAY OUTPUT AND CLEAR UP TEST DATA*/
SELECT * FROM #tmp1

DROP TABLE #tmp1
```

You could set this to run in a scheduled job to update your records as frequently as you see fit.

Might not be a perfect solution for you but hopefully a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for how long it's taken me to come back to this. I got pulled into some more pressing deliverables. I ended up figuring out how to get it working by storing the queries in one table as records, then running them using an execute immediate command. I've included the code below in case someone can use it in the future.

```
create table text_kw_search_queries
(
incident_number varchar2(15),
description varchar2(100),
topic_level_1 varchar2(89),
topic_level_2 varchar2(89)
);

DECLARE 
V_SQL VARCHAR2(1000);
CURSOR UPTO IS
SELECT TOPIC_level_1, TOPIC_level_2, description FROM tcstopic
;

BEGIN
FOR i IN UPTO LOOP

V_SQL := 'INSERT /*+APPEND PARALLEL(TEXT_KW_SEARCH_LOOP,2)*/ INTO text_kw_search_queries
SELECT
t2.Incident_Number,
t2.description,
t2.TOPIC_level_1,
t2.TOPIC_level_2
FROM (
SELECT 
t1.Incident_number,
t1.description,
'''||i.TOPIC_level_1||''' AS TOPIC_level_1, 
'''||i.TOPIC_level_2||''' AS TOPIC_level_2,
(CASE WHEN '|| i.description ||' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FLAG
FROM cso_text_query t1
) t2
WHERE t2.FLAG = 1';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SQL);

COMMIT WORK;
END LOOP;
END;
```